# Can't filter aggregated Neo4j query with property

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a query summarize nodes and relationships as groups, and i cant make it get filtered by property. Query below:

```
CALL apoc.nodes.group(['*'],["workspace"]) YIELD nodes, relationships
Unwind nodes as node
unwind relationships as rel
WITH coalesce(node) as result, rel
return result
```

Result shows that
[image: Result Image]

But I can't access with result.workspace, it shows me [] empty arrays.
I want to be able to filter with result.workspace = '100'

EDIT:
I have added new screenshot which showing result of query. I'm trying to achieve get only gray ones which have property 'workspace':'100' (It can be for example '99' as my query) and not the others like greens which 'workspace':'99' or with the different properties.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsqMx.png)

EDIT2:
With this query it returns nothing

CALL apoc.nodes.group(['*'],['workspace']) YIELD nodes
UNWIND nodes as node
WITH node
WHERE node.workspace = '100'
RETURN node

[Image after query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm8Ry.png)

PROBLEM SOLVED with query below:

CALL apoc.nodes.group(['*'],['workspace']) YIELD nodes,relationships
UNWIND nodes as node
UNWIND relationships as rel
WITH node, rel
WHERE apoc.any.properties(node).workspace = '100'
RETURN node,rel

apoc.any.properties() works on virtual nodes like they are real nodes.

Comment: Can you explain, in words, what information you are trying to extract? Your query has many issues, but it is hard to advise you without understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a graph contains different labels. For example three node with label "global_average_pooling2d_1" and three with "reshape_1". They are connected to each other. These nodes have a property "workspace" which i want to group them with this property. "workspace" property can be equal to '100', '99', '4' and so on. I managed to group them as i wanted. But when i group them over workspace property, I see '99' workspace and '100' workspace node group as result. I want to achieve just* to see 'workspace':'100' group. So I need to filter result only return group node with workspace:100 @cybersam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

This will return only the group nodes that have the `workspace` property value '100':

```
CALL apoc.nodes.group(['*'],["workspace"]) YIELD nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
WITH node
WHERE apoc.any.property(node, 'workspace') = '100'
RETURN node
```

*NOTE: You have to use the `apoc.any.property` function to get a property value from a virtual node.*

Comment: It returns me (no changes, no records). On the code tab response is [ ]
Edit: I need relationships also

Comment: Is the stored property value a string ('100') or numeric (`100`)? If the latter use `WHERE node.workspace = 100`. Getting the associated relationships is a *lot more work*, since presumably the relationships do not have the "workspace" property.

Comment: It should be '100' and i tried ur suggestion even query below. Its same sadly

CALL apoc.nodes.group(['*'],['workspace']) YIELD nodes
UNWIND nodes as node
WITH node
WHERE node.workspace = 100 or node.workspace = '100'
RETURN node

Comment: Does `CALL apoc.nodes.group(['*'],["workspace"]) YIELD nodes` return anything?

Comment: Yess all the nodes with grouping. For example in table tab : { "count_*" : 3, "workspace": "100"} and other nodes with same structure.

Comment: Thanks for help! Problem solved with apoc.any.properties(node).workspace = '100'

Comment: See also my updated answer, using `apoc.any.property`.